# Can't set FXML label from controller

Tags: javafx, fxml

I can't work out how to set the value of a Label defined in FXML from the controller initializer.

In my FXML I have (in a HBox):

```
<Label text="Label: " />
<Label fx:id="myLabel" />
```

And in the controller I have:

```
@FXML
private Label myLabel;

@FXML 
private void initialize() {
    myLabel.setText("Hello!");
}
```

The label stays blank when I run the program. What am I doing wrong? (I *suspect* initialize() is not running - the Eclipse debugger doesn't stop in it when I set a breakpoint - but I'm not sure and I can't get JavaFX to respect console printf statements for me to do debug print statements.)

Comment: Create and post a [MCVE]. You can do this by adding just a handful of lines to the code you posted (header info for the FXML, plus the root `HBox` element and class declaration and imports to the controller) and a minimal application class. The code you posted will work just fine, so either something is different in your actual project, or you're doing something else wrong somewhere in the code you omitted.

Comment: Make sure your controller class is implementing the Initializable interface. Also maybe remove the @FXML tag from the initialize method.

Comment: Oh it's definitely the first. There is no way you're implementing the Initializable interface, as the signature of the initialize method you're using is different from the initialize method of the initializable interface. So what you do is `<MyClass> implements Initializable {`

Comment: @JawnyThompson The requirement for a controller class to implement `Initializable` was removed in version 2.1. Also, the `@FXML` annotation is required on the `initialize()` method if it is not public, which it is not in this case. As I mentioned in my comment, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the code that is posted: I copied it verbatim, did the minimum required to make it a complete application, and it ran exactly as expected with the label displaying the `"Hello!"` text.

Comment: Oh i realize that. He's though trying to utilize the initialize method to initialize his labels text. I'm assuming he's trying to use the default initialize mechanism in JavaFx, as i don't see he's calling the initialize method from his fxml. Maybe he does in his real source code.

Comment: "the @FXML annotation is required on the initialize() method if it is not public, which it is not in this case." Didn't know about that, thanks

Comment: @JawnyThompson Again, you don't need to implement the  `Initializable` interface. *If you have an  `initialize()`* method (either one with no parameters or with the same parameters as the one in that interface, and that is either public or `@FXML`-annotated), it will be called by reflection by the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: @James_D
Oh got it! So it just has to be called initialize, alright fair enough :)

Comment: @James_D
You know coming to think about it, i wish i'd known about this before. The more you know!

Comment: @JawnyThompson The documentation concerning FXML and `FXMLLoader` is pretty meager. [This document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html), while containing some fairly obvious errors, is worth reading carefully in its entirety. You can experiment when you come across the inconsistencies to get a pretty reliable idea of what they intended to write. ;)

Comment: The documentation on Initializable comes as close to deprecating it as it can without actually using the word "deprecated", which is why I didn't use it.

By the way, ultimately I want to bind the label text to a variable - just setting the text is a simplification I made to try to work out how to get it done. (If I could get the label text to follow a property in my code without setting it up in Initialize, that would solve my current problem, though I'd still like to know the answer for future reference).

Comment: Ok, sorted it - the controller wasn't being successfully linked to the FXML, so indeed `ìnitialize` wasn't being called. Particular thanks to  @JawnyThompson for confirming the bits I quoted were ok. Had that been a reply rather than a comment I could have given you the tick for resolving it.